# How to create pyspark rdd from hazelcast map

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am working on writing the spark mlib where I need to read data from hazelcast map and want to create RDD/dataset/dataframe from hazelcast map.

So I have data in the form of key and value in the hazelcast map. 
And I want to create pyspark pair rdd with it, I dont know how to do it.

This is data I have in the form of key value pair in hazelcast map-

```
key: '8e5d78d2-8feb-41cd-9e1a-166fbe11c569' 
value: '2,-0.425965884412454,0.960523044882985'
key: 'dfea4b0a-c6f8-4e14-8543-edc53a9d9e07'
value: '2,-1.15823309349523,0.877736754848451'
```

This is my pyspark mlib program where I am reading from hazelcast map.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import *

import hazelcast, logging
from pyspark.rdd import RDD
config = hazelcast.ClientConfig()
config.network_config.addresses.append('localhost:5701')    
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
client = hazelcast.HazelcastClient(config)

############################################

from pyspark import SparkContext, rdd
spark = SparkContext()

# Here my_map is hazelcast map how do I create RDD/dataframe/dataset from this map.
my_map = client.get_map("fraudinputs").blocking()

for key, value in my_map.items:
    print "key:", key, "value:", value

client.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is read the file using `sparkContext.textFile`

```
rdd = sc.textFile("path to the data file")
```

Then you separate the `rdd` into *key rdd* and *value rdd*

```
keys = rdd.filter(lambda x: x.find("key") != -1).map(lambda x: x.split("=")[1])
values = rdd.filter(lambda x: x.find("value") != -1).map(lambda x: x.split("=")[1])
```

final step is to combine them to pair using zip

```
paired = keys.zip(values)
```

you should have following output

```
(u" '8e5d78d2-8feb-41cd-9e1a-166fbe11c569' ", u" '2,-0.425965884412454,0.960523044882985'")
(u" 'dfea4b0a-c6f8-4e14-8543-edc53a9d9e07'", u" '2,-1.15823309349523,0.877736754848451'")
```